# Which Banach algebras $A$ have properties $A \neq [A, A]$ and $A=\overline{[A, A]}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

In the study of commutators. The important question is whether the linear span of commutators [A, A] is closed in norm topology. In particular, we shall discuss the case that algebra is unital and simple. The following question is naturally raised.

Let $A$ be an infinite dimensional unital simple Banach algebra. Let $[A, A]$ denote the linear span of commutators in $A$, where a commutator in $A$ is an element of the form $xy-yx$, $x, y \in A$. We say that $A$ has property $\mathbb{X}$ if $A \neq [A, A]$ and $A=\overline{[A, A]}$, where $\overline{[A, A]}$ denotes the norm closure of $[A, A]$.

$\textbf{Question}$:

Which infinite dimensional unital simple Banach algebras $A$ have properties $A \neq [A, A]$ and $A=\overline{[A, A]}$?

We note that the question has no solution if A is a C*-algebra. This is due to C. Pop's results.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: We note that the question has no solution if A is a C*-algebra. This is due to C. Pop's results.